# Idea: Download Sources option not found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I use idea 2023.1.2, jdk 1.8.0_371, maven 3.6.3.
When I click into `java.lang.System`, I found it was decompiled .class file not source file. It's not convenient for me to read the detail.

[decompiled .class file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnM6n.png)

If I change the jdk to 17.0.5, and click into `java.lang.System`, it was revealed in source code, which is what I want.

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yasno.png)

Further more, if I add third-party dependencies to `pom.xml`, download dependencies, and finally reload the project. When I click into third-party dependency java class to see the detail, the file was also revealed in .class not source code.

And there's no `Download Sources` or `Choose Sources` options.

[no Download Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmvqS.png)

I have download source and documentation by clicking Maven `Download Sources and Documentation`. I want to see source code of any jave class

Comment: Make sure that the Java Bytecode Decompiler and Bytecode Viewer bundled plugins are enabled. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/decompiler.html

Comment: Yes I did enable Java Bytecode Decompiler and Bytecode Viewer bundled plugins. And there's no magic. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which disk your JDK is installed on. Then install the idea on the same disk as jdk.

If it still doesn't work, try installing the idea on the C disk.

Before reinstalling, you must uninstall idea and delete folders:

```
C:\Users\{$username}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains
C:\Users\{$username}\AppData\Local\JetBrains
```

and delete Windows registry folder:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs\jetbrains
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated to download source code in case needed...(checkbox for "Automatically download:" ?

Also check if you are using the most recent version of IDEA IntelliJ

[image]

And I would recomment to use the most [recent version of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) because 3.6.1 is a bit out of date.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong version of maven, actually it is 3.6.3.  The newest maven version 3.9.3 does not seems to work either. And I did activate downloading source code (all checkbox for "Automatically download:" ).  But one thing strange is that on another computer(also Windows 11),  with the same condition provided by my post, it is normal. Anyway, thanks for your sharing.